# Checking if caller and parameter are the same

Tags: c++, class, parameters, this, derived-class

For example I have four classes like:

```
class A;

class B{
protected:
    void check(const A &a); 
};

class C : public A, public B;
class D : public B;
```

Now I would like to write check function that does nothing if the caller and parameter are the same:

```
void B::check(const A &a){
   if(*this != a){
      //do something
   }
   else{
      //do nothing
   }
}
```

However this won't compile as class B doesn't know anything about class C, which will one day call B's function check on itself. It would be easy to cast `this` into A, but that would give an error if one day class D would call that check as it has nothing to do with A. How is such thing done then?

Edit: I might had to mention that class C and D will have interface for calling that check which is not avalible outside these classes, but it'll do nothing more than just pass parameter to inner function

Comment: How are you going to call the `check()` function ? Can you give example ?

Comment: This doesn't compile because there's no `operator!=` for types `B` and `A`, not because of the reason you give. Please clarify.

Comment: @iammilind as you can see B is designed only to be inherited, so only way to call B is through C or D e.g. C c; A a; c.check(a); c.check(c); d.check(c).. etc

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes I get the same error as you, but it's because these 2 doesn't anything to comapre against.. or is it not?

Comment: @Raven: it's because you haven't overloaded `operator!=`. You cannot compare non-scalar types unless you overload the operators yourself.

Comment: Can you update the same in your question in clearer manner, so that everyone can refer the single passage

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, this is something multimethods would solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work if you add a virtual destructor to A:

```
void B::check(const A &a)
{
    if (dynamic_cast<const B*>(&a) == this)
    {
        std::cout << "same object" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it won't. `B` is not a base class of `A`, which makes this ill-formed. (See 5.2.7/5)

Comment: This is not ill-formed, because `A` becomes a polymorphic type when adding a virtual destructor (See 5.2.7/6).

Comment: Ah, right. And then 5.2.7/8 second bullet applies (the cross-cast). { Blergh, I hate requirements of the form "1. A must be X. 2. except that A can be Y" }. Upvoted.

Comment: Upvoted & answer: first of all it's working, it doesn't introduce many changes to code and also looks good and meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(*this != a)
```

Check is meaningless because this(class B) will never be same as type of class A because both are unrelated classes.

It is not clear what you want to do, but if you want your Base class pointer to be pointing to your derived class object then there must be a inheritance(is-a) relationship between them.

Comment: however if B was inherited by C, `this` pointer is C and that one is related to A actually...

Comment: @Raven: That's just saying, "however, if the question was a different one, this answer wouldn't apply". Clarify your question to ask what you really mean.

Comment: I think that "However" thing was well said by code I posted.. it can be seen that C is derived as well as D and I've said I'll call check for C and D only (as B have no public interface)

Comment: The problem is that A and B are only indirectly related by class C, and neither A nor B is really aware of C. Except, of course, when 5.2.7/7 applies. See my solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's only one possible escape hatch here. If *both* A and B have a virtual function, then you can `dynamic_cast` both `this` and `&a`. And per 5.2.7/7 "If T is “pointer to cv void,” then the result is a pointer to the most derived object pointed to by v."

Therefore, this code works:

```
void B::check(const A &a){
   if(dynamic_cast<void const*>(const_cast<B const>(this) != dynamic_cast<void const*>(&a)) {
      //do something
   } ...
```

Nothing else gets you a **pointer to the most derived object** without knowing that type.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check whether the instances are the same:

```
void B::check(const A &a){
   if(this != &a){
      //do something
   }
   else{
      //do nothing
   }
}
```

Comparing the content of different classes doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: `this != &a` is always false because both are unrelated classes

Comment: This doesn't make sense, either: You can neither convert `A*` to `B*` nor `B*` to `A*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
void check(const A &a){
   if((void*)this != (void*)&a){
      //do something
   }
   else{
      //do nothing
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will NOT catch the case of `class C: A, B`. The `A` and `B` subobjects are distinct.

Comment: Yes. Both conversions are defined by 4.10/2. This returns the storage locations of A and B, respectively. I think your example is really tricky because of the two empty-base optimizations that are possible. Add an `int foo` member to each, and they must be distinct so `((A*)(void*)(&a))->foo` becomes a valid way and unique way to refer to the `foo` in `A`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for — to check whether `this` and `a` are both parts of the same object of type `C`?

```
void B::check(A &a)
{
    std::cout << (static_cast<C*>(this) != static_cast<C*>(&a)) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    C c;
    D d;
    A& a1 = c;
    A a2;
    boolalpha(std::cout);
    c.check(a1); // false
    c.check(a2); // true
    d.check(a1); // true
}
```

Comment: This should be a `dynamic_cast`. The `static_cast` would produce Undefined Behavior if `*this` isn't actually a `C`. Also, note that "class B doesn't know anything about class C" according to the question (i.e. you can't check this for all possible types)